# How do you get age of last measurement in grafana/influxql?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql

A watchdog process reports host "liveness" by writing a measurement in influxdb, e.g.

`watchdog,host=host_xyz alive=1`

I'm interested in showing in Grafana when too much time has passed since the last measurement. Is there a way to query such information from Influx?

(A similar question was asked here also 9 months ago, but there's no answer to it: [InfluxQL: age of record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392860/influxql-age-of-record)
Is it possible that a time series database can't give the age of a record?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Grafana under Edit > Visualization > Value > Show: you can choose "Time of last point".

This will show the timestamp of the last point in InfluxDB. This is how I do it.

The downside to this is that if the timestamp is not added in real time (i.e. you add a previous of future timestamp in InfluxDB) then the data will be off. (though these cases are more rare).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It is not exactly a solution for what I had in mind, but it helps; I'm also accepting the answer since apparently there is no other way to do this with influx.

Comment: I know, ideally Influx would give us the value, but I too don't know how to do that (or if possible).